CPU has only 2/3 performance despite same amount of cores and same frequency
I have 3 PC builds with a Ryzen 9 3900X for mining.
Two of them run at a speed of 95 it/s while consuming 150-160W.
But one of them with roughly identical specs runs at 65 it/s while consuming around 120-130W.
The system shows the exact same core count (24) and roughly the same frequency (4017MHz at /proc/cpuinfo)
Interestingly, the one that is slower actually has a huge tower cooler and the CPU runs at 52 degrees C, which I think is quite low temp. The other ones have the box AMD coolers and run at 74 C.
The "faulty" CPU did fall on the ground while first installing it, although it resulted only in bent pins, which I managed to straighten with a kitchen knife and get it working correctly.
Do you think the fall might have affected the CPU performance?
If so, how come a CPU with the same amount of cores on the same frequency has a different performance? Is it caused by like CPU errors or something?

What memory quantity and type is in each system?

Are RAM (not only installed, but system accessible and confirmed working) and PCIe devices (again, confirmed working) the same? Maybe you have damaged a memory/PCIe controller in the CPU and you're not actually using all of your RAM sticks, or maybe a PCIe link to your GPU, storage, etc is not of the width you expect.

What kind of mining are you doing? Is it based on storage, or CPU or GPU? If CPU then is your RAM properly working in dual-channel mode on all systems? If storage based do all systems have the same amount and speed of storage? If GPU are they all the same GPU and is the PCIe link the same?

exact same core count (24) ... you mean (12) right? consuming 150-160W that's not the CPU power is it, since the 3900X is apparently a 105W CPU - perhaps, if you're overclocking, you have two CPU's that can handle better OC than the third one - doesn't mean the third one is faulty, just means the other two are more overclockable

There are absolutely no PCIe devices, not even a graphics card. It is just pure CPU mining, based on AI training so matrix multiplication and stuff like that, it doesn't actually need much RAM at all. I mean there's 24 logical cores, 12 physical, 150-160W is the draw from the wall, I'm not overclocking. I'm just curious how come can those CPUs have roughly the same frequency on every core, yet one is slower than the other. Are there any strictly CPU benchmark tools for Linux I could try?
